# How to pass a array's total elements as an function's postion parameter?

Tags: c

I had a array in c:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and I had a function's protype like this:

```
int add_all(int a, int b, int c, int d);
```

But how can I pass the array's all elements as the function's parameter at one time?

I know in python, this can be done like this:

```
array=[1,2,3,4]
add_all(*array)
```

Could someone tell me how to achieve the same effect in C?

Comment: @AhmedM.Farrag Adding tags that aren't relevant to the question, so you can post an answer that relies on that tag is not ok.

Comment: @2501: ok. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
int add_all(array, 4);
```

When you call a function, and you try to pass it an array, this array
will be converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Function prototype

```
int add_all(int[] , int size);
```

or

```
int add_all(int* , int size);
```

Comment: Thank you. I know what you said, but I don't want to change my function. So I need some magic methods in the process of passing parameters.

Comment: @RyanLi There are not magic methods, you will have to pass 4 arguments. You can either change the function or write a function wrapper.

Comment: @2501 Thank you. Maybe the function wrapper is indeed what I need. So, could you show me how to write a wrapper based on my problem. I'll really appreciate.

Comment: @RyanLi Function wrapper is just a normal function that takes you arguments and calls the function you wanted to call in the first place.

Comment: @2501 Ok, I know what you said. But I was stuck in the problem that how to pass the arguments to the function I want to call.　I can write the protye of the wrapper.                                        　　　　　　　　 int  wraper(int (*fun)(int, int, int, int,), int   *array, int size) {                        /*how to pass the parameter? */                                                                                                                 }

Comment: @RyanLi `fun( array[0] , array[1] , array[2] , array[3] )`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/while.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/reverse.hpp>

#define ARRAY_ELEM(x,n) x[n]

#define PRED(n, state) BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, state)

#define OP(d, state) \
   OP_D( \
      d, \
      BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 0, state), \
      BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 1, state), \
      BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3, 2, state) \
   ) 

#define OP_D(d, res, c, arr_name) \
   ( \
      BOOST_PP_TUPLE_PUSH_BACK(res,ARRAY_ELEM(arr_name,BOOST_PP_DEC(c))), \
      BOOST_PP_DEC(c), \
      arr_name \
   ) \


#define UNPACK_REVERSE(ARR_NAME,N) \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM( \
      3, 0, \
      BOOST_PP_WHILE(PRED, OP, ((ARRAY_ELEM(ARR_NAME,BOOST_PP_DEC(N))), \
                    BOOST_PP_DEC(N),ARR_NAME) ) \
   )
/*The macro to be called*/
#define UNPACK(ARR_NAME,N) \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REVERSE(UNPACK_REVERSE(ARR_NAME,N))
```

And here's a usage example:

```
void print3(int x, int y, int z){
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n",x,y,z);
}
int main(){
    int z[3]={1,2,3};
    print3 UNPACK(z,3);
    return 0;
}
```

This macro uses Boost's Preprocessor library in a loop to generate and expand the array elements in a tuple. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice method: +1

Comment: Very nice, thank you. But I'm working with C langue, so I'm not familiar with Boost library in C++.

Comment: @RyanLi: This is C not C++.