# How to pass a 2-dimensional list to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, function

this is my first post.

The Problem:
I have 2-Dimensional-list which is decleared and filled in a function - looks like this: `data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]` - Now I want to pass that list from this function to another to continue working with the list.

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I am very new to programming and I don't know much about it. I have a function which calculates something and fills the list with it, with a for x in range - loop. I want to give the whole list to another function and in the other function work with the list with Mathplotlib to print a chart.

Comment: This is simply calling a function with a parameter. At this level you are much better off with programming classes and tutorials [like this one on functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) than asking here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a array's total elements as an function's postion parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387943/how-to-pass-a-arrays-total-elements-as-an-functions-postion-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that you're wanting to do something like this:

```
def myfunction():
   data = [[1,2,3,4],[10,20,30,40]]
   return data

def function2(myList):
    # do stuff with it here

myList = myfunction()
function2(myList)
```

But your question is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks I will try it, I think you helped me with this. Sorry for my bad expression of my question. I'm new to programming and my English is not the best. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not an issue with python. Python allows You to pass multidimension lists to functions.
There shouldn't be any issue with this.
just pass like a simple variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know your problem, it is the same process to pass a multidimensional array to a function as any other variable, the problem is other code, python is really annoying with tabs and spaces and it can cause confusing errors aside from the usual inconsistent use of tabs and spaces error. Just try deleting the function that's not working and rewrite it and you'll probably fix your error

Comment: You are making assumptions about the problem. OP claims not to know how to pass the list to another function, how does deleting and rewriting help?

Comment: you just pass the variable with the array to the function, op clearly knows how to do that, what else would it be? somtimes its hard to spot a typo or subtle error and its faster to just rewrite it

Comment: OP clearly doesn't know how to call a function. And without that basic knowledge on OP's part, how are we to answer it? This person will be much better off with beginner programming resources available on the net.